# .val() function doesn't detect zero

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using jQuery to prevent writing the wrong number in input. In my case `.val()` function doesn't detect 0 in number. When I'm writing in input 2, 5, 3 it works but for 2, 500, 30 it doesn't.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#desire_point').on('change', function() {
    if (this.value < $('#min_value').val()) {
      $('#desire_point').addClass('is-invalid')
      $('#btnSbmt').attr('disabled', true)
    } else if (this.value > $('#max_value').val()) {
      $('#desire_point').addClass('is-invalid')
      $('#btnSbmt').attr('disabled', true)
    } else if (this.value < $('#max_value').val()) {
      $('#desire_point').removeClass('is-invalid')
      $('#btnSbmt').attr('disabled', false)
    } else if (this.value > $('#min_value').val()) {
      $('#desire_point').removeClass('is-invalid')
      $('#btnSbmt').attr('disabled', false)
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" id="min_value" type="number">
<input class="form-control" id="max_value" type="number">
<input class="form-control" id="desire_point" type="number">
<input class="form-control" id="btnSbmt" type="submit">
```

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific about what you mean by the code "not working" for 2, 500, 30? Please try to answer these questions: 1) What is the code supposed to check? 2) What is the expected output for 2, 500, 30?  3) What output are you getting?

Comment: Side note, you should be using `.prop()`, not `.attr()` in `$('#btnSbmt').attr('disabled', false)`

Comment: where is the problem, the code seems to work +1 @AnujKhandelwal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try it this way

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // By default the button is disabled
  $('#btnSbmt').attr('disabled', true)
  // Chaged to keyup from chage - to make it realtime - you may want to change it back based on your use case
  $('#desire_point').on('keyup', function() {

      // Declare vars and set datatype
      var desiredVal = parseInt(this.value);
      var minVal = parseInt($('#min_value').val());
      var maxVal = parseInt($('#max_value').val());
      // Changed the way you are working out the val
      if (desiredVal >= minVal & desiredVal <= maxVal) {
        $('#btnSbmt').attr('disabled', false);
      } else {
        $('#btnSbmt').attr('disabled', true);
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#desire_point').on('change', function() {
    if (+this.value < +$('#min_value').val()) {
      $('#desire_point').addClass('is-invalid')
      $('#btnSbmt').attr('disabled', true)
    } else if (+this.value > +$('#max_value').val()) {
      $('#desire_point').addClass('is-invalid')
      $('#btnSbmt').attr('disabled', true)
    } else if (+this.value < +$('#max_value').val()) {
      $('#desire_point').removeClass('is-invalid')
      $('#btnSbmt').attr('disabled', false)
    } else if (+this.value > +$('#min_value').val()) {
      $('#desire_point').removeClass('is-invalid')
      $('#btnSbmt').attr('disabled', false)
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What's this? Please explain your answer and don't just dump code, expecting everyone to figure out what you did.

Answer (score 0):

Or, in case you don't want to restrict your input to integers you could do it like this:

```js
$('#btnSbmt').attr('disabled',true)
$('#desire_point').on('keyup', function() {
  var inv = +this.value;
  inv=inv<+$('#min_value').val()
   || inv>+$('#max_value').val();
  $('#btnSbmt').attr('disabled',inv);
  $(this).toggleClass('is-invalid',inv);
});
```

```css
.is-invalid {color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" id="min_value" type="number">
<input class="form-control" id="max_value" type="number">
<input class="form-control" id="desire_point" type="number">
<input class="form-control" id="btnSbmt" type="submit">
```